# AngularJs directive view not updating on ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have directive with ng-repeat inside. And I have toggle function inside that changing order of array items. When I'm displaying scope model I see that items changing their order but UI not updating. Tried scope.$apply() but it says that process busy.

```
.directive('example', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        template: `
                Checking model: {{model}}

                <div ng-repeat="(key, row) in model">
                        <div ng-hide="key == 0">
                            <div class="icon-arrow-u" ng-hide="$first" ng-click="moveUp(key)"></div>
                            <div class="icon-delete" ng-click="removeCell(key)"></div>
                            <div class="icon-arrow-d" ng-hide="$last" ng-click="moveDown(key)"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        `,
        scope: {
            model: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, element) {
            scope.moveItem = function (origin, destination) {
                var temp = scope.model[destination];
                scope.model[destination] = scope.model[origin];
                scope.model[origin] = temp;
            };

            scope.moveUp = function(index) {
                scope.moveItem(index, index - 1);
            }

            scope.moveDown = function(index) {
                scope.moveItem(index, index + 1);
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing a code fiddle, I'd guess that the reason lies within the `ng-repeat` directive. You should add a `track by` expression (see [AngularJS doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat))

For example you could write `(key, row) in model track by key` or `(key, row) in model track by row`. Either way it has to be a value that's unique to every row.

Comment: "track by key" worked. Weird cause when I tried "track by $index" it didn't make any changed. Thank you!

Comment: That's because you are iterating over an object. Also "track by $index" only works when the index of elements won't change.

Answer (score 1):

Scope is isolated when a [directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) is used. You need to apply the scope to see the changes.

Add the following code on each function in the link or whenever the event is called.

Inside link function use :

```
        if (scope.$root.$$phase != '$apply' &&
            scope.$root.$$phase != '$digest') {
            scope.$apply();

        }
```

From main controller

```
        if ($scope.$root.$$phase != '$apply' &&
            $scope.$root.$$phase != '$digest') {
            $scope.$apply();

        }
```

if that doesn't work, try calling this on each event.

```
function apply(scope) {
  if (!scope.$$phase && !scope.$root.$$phase) {
    scope.$apply();
    console.log("Scope Apply Done !!");
  } 
  else {
    console.log("Scheduling Apply after 200ms digest cycle already in progress");
    setTimeout(function() {
        apply(scope)
    }, 200);
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Did you use that exact syntax? If it says it is busy then might help to use it with $timeout as last resort.